# How to output RandomForest Classifier from python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have trained a RandomForestClassifier from Python Sckit Learn Module with very big dataset, but question is how can I possibly save this model and let other people apply it on their end.
Thank you!

Comment: See http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html#model-persistence

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The recommended method is to use `joblib`, this will result in a much smaller file than a pickle:

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
joblib.dump(clf, 'filename.pkl') 

#then your colleagues can load it

clf = joblib.load('filename.pkl')
```

See the [online docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/model_persistence.html)

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried pickling the `RandomForestClassifier` using the Pickle module and then saving it to the disk?

Here’s an example based on the [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pickle.html) docs:

```
import pickle

classifier = RandomForestClassifier(etc)
output = open('classifier.pkl', 'wb')
pickle.dump(classifier, output)
output.close()
```

The “other people” could then reload the pickled object as follows:

```
import pickle

f = open('classifier.pkl', 'rb')
classifier = pickle.load(f)
f.close()
```

Comment: joblib is preferred and less verbose (i.e. smaller file): http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html#model-persistence