# Is it feasible to do the prediction without running the model everytime, just by calling the equation of my train model to predict the test dataset?

Tags: python

I am running a linear equation and random forest model and every time i have to run a huge train data set to generate the model and eventually using the model to predict the test data set.
Is it possible to use only the equation of the model rather running the whole program as it takes a lot of time for prediction of the test data set?

Comment: What exactly do you want to use the equation for?

Comment: I would like to predict the test dataset

Comment: I do not follow the question. There is no equation for a random forest model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure thing you can use just the equation for your linear model. You just need to access coefficients and bias to do it. The way to do it depends on the framework you are using.

For example, you can see the `coeff_` attribute in [`sklearn` documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html).

To save and then reuse the Random Forest model is a lot trickier.

The universal solution will be:

1. Train your model.
2. Serialize it with [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) to a file.
3. Whenever you need to make predictions just deserialize the file with the model and use it.

[More information about how to serialize a model with `pickle` or `joblib`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23000693/how-to-output-randomforest-classifier-from-python).

Also, different frameworks usually have built-in interfaces for model serialization.